# Small android app generates cumulatively large files

Tags: android

My old computer recently crashed so I did a restore to a new PC of my android projects. I was somewhat surprised to see that the files took up so much room. My project is only a few MBs in size - xml, layout, assets, source code and so on.
But the project size is several GB, and this is mainly confined to the app/src/build/intermediate directory. I do regular clean and rebuild projects and also occasional invalidate cache and restart.
The number of files in this one directory is in excess of 100,000!

Is it safe to delete this directory? I don't want to do anything that will impact on future work with my project.

Could this also be the reason why gradle sync and indexing takes so long? It can take up to a few minutes and I lose the will to live while the PC churns away.

Also: a general question - are there any folders that can be safely deleted? I think someone on one of these forums said that .gradle can be removed without problems?

Sorry if this is a kindergarten question, I was genuinely surprised to find out that the project had swelled so much.

Answer (score 1):

Delete build directory. Check your .gitignore file if its there.
.gitignore contains all files you can safely delete without harming the build on your next machine.

Sample gitignore file

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the ART/Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/
out/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Android Studio Navigation editor temp files
.navigation/

# Android Studio captures folder
captures/

# IntelliJ
*.iml
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/assetWizardSettings.xml
.idea/dictionaries
.idea/libraries
.idea/caches

# Keystore files
# Uncomment the following line if you do not want to check your keystore files in.
#*.jks

# External native build folder generated in Android Studio 2.2 and later
.externalNativeBuild

# Freeline
freeline.py
freeline/
freeline_project_description.json

# fastlane
fastlane/report.xml
fastlane/Preview.html
fastlane/screenshots
fastlane/test_output
fastlane/readme.md
```

Comment: Thank you - is there any way to stop all these files being generated, or at least, be autodeleted?

Comment: Android studio needs these files to build your project. You can write a shell script to delete all of them. Although next time when you open Studio you will see them created again.

Comment: Hi Shashank, thanks! Several GB of files for such a small project is ridiculous! I don't mind if the files are auto generated when studio is opened, but this looks like they have been building up for some time. There are files dating back to last December!